# Under which circumstances can documents insert with insert_many not appear in DB

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

We are using pymongo 3.12 and Python 3.12, MongoDB 4.2. We write results of our task from Celery worker process into MongoDB using pymongo. MongoClient is not instantiated each time, thus, we use connection pooling and reuse the connections. There are multiple instances of Celery workers competing for running a job, so our Celery server has multiple connections to MongoDB.

The problem: sometimes, results of that particular operation are not in MongoDB, however, no error is logged, and our code captures all exceptions, so it looks like no exception ever happens. We use plain insert_many with default parameters, which means our insert is ordered and any failure would trigger an error. Only this particular operation fails, others that read or write data from/to the same or another MongoDB instance work fine. Problem can be reproduced in different systems. We have added maxIdleTimeMS parameter to MongoDB connection in order to close idle connections, but it did not help.

Is there a way to tell programmatically which local port is used by pymongo connection which is going to serve my request?

Comment: `insert_many` returns a [InsertManyResult](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/results.html#pymongo.results.InsertManyResult) - which has the inserted ids listed. This can tell if all documents are inserted.

Comment: @prasad_ thank you, will add logging of what `insert_many` returned. Documentation says insert may be not acknowledged in case of `write_concern` with `w=0`, however we don't use write concern directly. Anyway will be interesting to see what happens when data is not there.